# Printing a if function result from a string input in Python 3.6.4

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I would like to know how I could fix this code to print a result if the last piece of the input string is a certain letter or print an error if it doesn't match the available letters. I can get everything else to function but this.
The error I am getting is:

```
print("Your studying level is: ", x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

student_code = input("Insert your student code (123456ABCD): ")
def add():
    x = (student_code[10])
    if x == "B":
          print("Bachelor's")
    elif x == "M":
          print("Magister's")
    elif x == "D":
          print("Doctor's")
    else: print("false input.")
    if len(student_code) == 10:
        print("Your matricular number: ", student_code[:6])
        print("You enrolled in the year: ", student_code[:2])
        print("Your study plan is: ", student_code[6:])
        print("Your studying level is: ", x)
    else: print("Student code has been input improperly.")
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Copy-and-paste from your text editor, and then highlight the text selection and press ctrl-k to get auto-formatting

Answer (score 0):

You Just mess with your code you are given an eg string: **12345ABCD**  and try to access its **10th** index how it can be possible? and you just take input before calling the function? I tried to improve your answer which takes only string length as 10.

```
def add():
student_code = input("Insert your student code (123456ABCD): ")
if len(student_code) != 10 and len(student_code) > 10:
    print("Enter valid Student Code")
    student_code = input("Insert your student code (123456ABCD): ")
else:
    x = (student_code[9])
    if x == "B":
      print("Bachelor's")
    elif x == "M":
      print("Magister's")
    elif x == "D":
      print("Doctor's")
    else: print("false input.")
    print("Your matricular number: ", student_code[:5])
    print("You enrolled in the year: ", student_code[:1])
    print("Your study plan is: ", student_code[5:])
    print("Your studying level is: ", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Harsh Bhut, you made me realize that the index is looked for, it takes the next one from the index number. Another way to see it is that it starts from the 0th index. I managed to solve the issue thanks to that. The fixed code which works for me is:

```
student_code = input("Insert your student code (123456ABCD): ")
x = (student_code[9])
if x == "B":
        x = "Bachelor's"
elif x == "M":
        x = "Magister's"
elif x == "D":
        x = "Doctor's"
else: x = "false input"
if len(student_code) == 10:
    print("Your matricular number: ", student_code[:6])
    print("You enrolled in the year: ", student_code[:2])
    print("Your study plan is: ", student_code[6:])
    print("Your studying level is: ", x)
else: print("Student code has been input improperly.")
```